# Curl command line to send email via gmail

Tags: windows, curl, command-line, gmail

Hi I have had a search on this already and I cannot work out why this keeps failing. I'm using the following curl command to send an email via a gmail account. fails on authentication.

I have tried two accounts one that has 2 factor setup with an app password, and one that just has less secure apps enabled.

both just fail to authenticate.

`curl --ssl-reqd --url smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 --mail-from myemail@gmail.com --mail-rcpt otheremail@gmail.com --user 'myemail@gmail.com:password' --cacert cacert.pem --upload-file mail.txt --TLSv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 --verbose`

the cacert.pem came from here https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

This is the output from curl

````
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 64.233.167.109:587...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (64.233.167.109) port 587 (#0)
< 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP v11sm289228wml.26 - gsmtp
> EHLO mail.txt
< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: c:\utils\curl-7.68.0-win64-mingw\bin\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [208 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [91 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2342 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [114 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=smtp.gmail.com
*  start date: Sep 22 15:25:59 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 15 15:25:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "smtp.gmail.com" matched cert's "smtp.gmail.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> EHLO mail.txt
{ [5 bytes data]
< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
} [5 bytes data]
> AUTH PLAIN
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{ [5 bytes data]
< 334
} [5 bytes data]
> ACdhbmR5cGRzMjAxNEBnbWFpbC5jb20AYW9ub3hubnB2Y3N3aGR1bic=
{ [5 bytes data]
< 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
< 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v11sm289228wml.26 - gsmtp
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
} [2 bytes data]
curl: (67) Login denied```


I cannot see why this is not working, I can use the app password in another app that does not use OAuth and that lets me send emails OK.

I'm new to using curl and any help will be apricated.

Thanks.
Andy.


Edit:  I have also tried this on my linuxVM and that worked fined with GMail, so I tried again in windows and still failed.  I just removed the quotes from the user field and it worked fine.
````

Answer (score 0):

So as I put in the edited question. I have solved it.

the --user 'myemail@gmail.com:password' need the single quotes removing from it and it now connects and sends the mail.

Hopefully this will aid someone else in the future.